# Input score out of 10 into UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to create a UITextField that users can enter a number between 1-10 in order to give a score out of ten. For example, 5/10, 9/10 etc.

Ideally I would like a user to only be able to enter 1 to 10 and it to be displayed as x/10. Where x is the user's inputted score.

I have been looking at using:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string
```

But I am not really sure what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Josh

Comment: Here you can check, whether the input is a digit or made of digits respectively and you can taylor the resulting string and parse that as a number and then see whether it is between 1 and 10. 
Do you want us to code that for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code hope it will satisfy all the condition you are looking for

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string
{
    NSString *resultingString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];

        if (resultingString.length > 2 && range.length == 0)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            if (resultingString.length<=1) {
                return YES;
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *firstDigit = [resultingString substringToIndex:1];
                NSString *secondDigit = [resultingString substringFromIndex:1];
                if ([firstDigit intValue]>1) {
                    return NO;
                }
                else if ([secondDigit intValue]>0)
                {
                    if ([firstDigit intValue]==0) {
                        return YES;
                    }
                    return NO;
                }
                else
                {
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This will allow you to enter numbers only in range 1-10

```
#define NUMBERS_ONLY @"1234567890"
#define CHARACTER_LIMIT 2

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSString *myTextField = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:filtered];
    return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= CHARACTER_LIMIT)&&(myTextField.integerValue<=10));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

This will limit the textfield to enter only one character

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

return (textField.text.length <= 0);
}
```

and set the keyboard type to Number Pad so that user is allowed to enter number only where user can enter only number between 0 to 9.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is issue doesn't it helped you?